# How to deploy hardhat contract to mainnet without ALCHEMY or INFURA?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, go-ethereum, hardhat

How to deploy hardhat contract to mainnet  without ALCHEMY or INFURA ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alchemy, Infura, and others, are services offering connection to nodes of the Ethereum network.

Contract deployment means that you broadcast a transaction with specific parameters (`data` field containing the compiled bytecode, `to` field empty). But you can only broadcast a transaction to the rest of the network from a node connected to the network.

So apart from using a third-party service, you can also run your own node. For example using the [go-ethereum](https://geth.ethereum.org/) client software.

Then you'll be able to broadcast the transaction through this your own node, instead of a third-party one.